# Selection Sort - Stack Overflow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, recursion, selection

Hi I am trying to implement Selection Sort in vb.net using recursion. Problem is that I keep getting stackoverflow if the array I want to sort is 1000 elements. I can't find the problem. I don't know much about stack overflow or how to check it. From my research the problem could be infinite recursion but I check for that and exit the sub.Here is the main code:

```
Public Class SelectionSort
Inherits DefaultSort


Public Sub New(ByVal num As Integer)
    Me.CreateArray(num)
    Me.ShowArray()
    Me.StartWatch()
    Me.Sort(Arr.Length - 1, 0, 1)
    Me.StopWatch()
    Me.ShowArray()
    Me.ShowExecutionTime()
End Sub





Private IsSorted As Boolean = False
Public Overridable Sub Sort(ByVal arrLen As Integer, ByVal pos As Integer, ByVal minval As Integer)



    If pos >= arrLen Then
        IsSorted = True
    End If

    If IsSorted = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If



    Dim minKey As Integer = Array.IndexOf(Arr, minval + pos)
    Dim temp As Integer = Arr(minKey)


    Arr(minKey) = Arr(pos)
    Arr(pos) = temp
    pos += 1

    Sort(arrLen, pos, minval)
    If pos >= arrLen Then
        IsSorted = True
    End If

    If IsSorted = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Everything inside the constructor is set in the base class "DefaultSort", except for the Sort(). The array is set using properties:

```
Public Overridable Property Arr() As Integer()

    Get
        Return _array
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value() As Integer)
        _array = value
    End Set

End Property
Private _array() As Integer
```

Everything should work as far as I know. It works on an array of 10 elements and an array of 100 elements.

Any ideas, stuck!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a recursion for this. Use an iterative solution instead

**Update:** 
If you look at doc for [StackOverflowExectpion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) it says

> The exception that is thrown when the
>   execution stack overflows because it
>   contains too many nested method calls.

The way this sort is written each element is visited with a recursive method call. e.g. the first element calls sort for the second element which calls sort for the third element and so on. This means that the recursion depth is equal to the number of member (I might be off by +/- 1).

This means that if you have enough elements you'll get a StackOverflow.

I copied your code and ran it and below is the truncated Call Stack thats shows that the sort gets called on each pos recursively and that it dies when there's more than 8,314 elements.

```
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8314, Integer minval = 1) Line 67 + 0xb bytes  Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8314, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8313, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8312, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8311, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8310, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8309, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8308, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8307, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8306, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8305, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8304, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8303, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SelectionSort.Sort(Integer arrLen = 10000, Integer pos = 8302, Integer minval = 1) Line 75 + 0x14 bytes Basic
```

Comment: Thanks, iterative works. Just out of curiousity any idea why stackoverfow occurred?

Comment: I'd venture a guess and say that you overflowed the stack.

Comment: the runtime stack is of limited size. Every time you call your selection sort method, it's adding several things to the stack (local variables, return address, parameters, etc.). When you get enough of these calls, the stack gets filled up and overflows.

Comment: Imagine a pez dispenser. Everytime you call a function, you push a pez into the slot. Everytime you leave a function, you push a pez out, and eat it.  Lets say you can fit 20 pez into your dispenser. What happens when you try to push the 21st in? Doesn't fit right? You've overflowed your pez dispenser.  Same concept applies here. When you sorted 10 or 100 you had plenty of room in your pez/stack. When you ran 1000 it ran out of room and now you have pez all over the place.

Comment: When I suggested providing your own stack, in pez terms I was saying, "make yourself a bigger pez dispenser, and use that instead"

Comment: Thanks Guys, now I have an iterative solution and know why stackoverflow occurred. Good work and great help.